# Port mapping problems with VScode OSS running inside a docker container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, binding

I would like to run the VSCode OSS Web Server within a Docker Container, as described here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#vs-code-for-the-web

The Container is running, but the port mapping doesn't work. I run my image with

`docker run -it -p 9888:9888 -p 5877:5877 vscode-server`

but I got nothing with `curl -I http://localhost:9888` on my machine. The VScode server is running, but the mapping to the host will not work. I think the problem is the binding. It looks like the VScode Server will bind to `127.0.0.1` but should bind to `0.0.0.0`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9888          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      870/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5877          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      881/node
```

Can anybody help here?